# C#: Why is Networkstream.Read() able to change the buffer variable without out/ref keyword

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, ref, out

Why can NetworkStream.Read() write to the byte[]?

```
byte[] data = new byte[16];

NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);
ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

//data != new byte[16]
```

I thought you need a out/ref keyword to write to a variable. like this:

```
ns.Read(out data, 0, data.Length);
```

If i try to recreate that method it doesnt work:

```
public static void testread(byte[] buffer, int size)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 1;
    }
    buffer = data;
}

byte[] data = new byte[16];
testread(data, data.Length);

//data == new byte[16]
```

But if I add the "out" keyword to testread() does work:

```
public static void testread(out byte[] buffer, int size)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 1;
    }
    buffer = data;
}

byte[] data = new byte[16];
testread(data, data.Length);

//data != new byte[16]
```

This proofs that you cant write to a variable without the "out"/"ref" keyword. But how does NetworkStream write to the byte[] without the "out"/"ref" keyword?
Scary..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This proofs that you cant write to a variable without the "out"/"ref" keyword.

You need to mentally separate two very different concepts:

- changing the state of an object
- reassigning the value of a variable (parameter, local, field, etc)

(noting that in the case of objects, the latter means changing the object that it refers to)

`out` is only needed for the **second** of these. `Stream` allows the caller to pass in an object (the array), and it writes into the array. No `out` is needed for this. It is no different to:

```
void SetCustomerName(Customer obj) { // for class Customer
    obj.Name = "Fred";
}
...
var x = new Customer();
SetCustomerName(x);
Console.WriteLine(x.Name); // prints "Fred"
```

This updates the object, but doesn't need to change the *parameter* to do so. It changes the *object that the parameter points to*.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because it doesn't do the `buffer = data` assignment. Instead it reads directly into the buffer passed as the argument, i.e. if you do `buffer[i] = 1` in your loop you emulate it.